# Display a Ph.D. Thesis title when using biblatex-chem

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `biblatex` with `biblatex-chem` and have I can't display the title of a Ph.D. thesis. I've dug around the documentation but have not found a solution. I've noticed biblatex treats a thesis differently to bibtex in the .bib but I don't know if this has an effect.

Here is the entry in the `si.bib`:

```
    @THESIS{xu_synthesis_2008,
      author = {Xu, Shu},
      title = {Synthesis of high quality {low-toxic} semiconductor nanocrystals},
      institution = {University of East Anglia},
      year = {2008},
      type = {{Ph.D. Thesis}},
      owner = {Paul},
      timestamp = {2011.08.25}
    }
```

Here is the document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage{lmodern}                    
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chem-angew, articletitle, chaptertitle, language=auto, doi, defernumbers=true]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{si.bib}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}    

\begin{document}
\nocite{xu_synthesis_2008}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this.

> [1] S. Xu, Ph.D. Thesis, University of East Anglia, 2008.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Which style do you mean? That I know of, none of the chemistry journals include thesis title in the output.

Comment: I'm writing in the style of Angewandte Chemie International Edition. It is much more likely it is my missunderstanding of the journals rules. Is there a way to turn it on if you want to bend the rules for a personal document?

Comment: The journal guidelines (http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/%28ISSN%291521-3773/homepage/2002_guideline.html) give only one example for a thesis, but this does not include the title.

Comment: Was this bug reported and/or fixed upstream?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the moment you can add the modification of the bibliography driver:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{thesis}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock%Added by Marco
  \usebibmacro{title}%Added by Marco
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{type}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{institution+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}
```

The whole example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{si.bib}
@PHDTHESIS{xu_synthesis_2008,
      author = {Xu, Shu},
      title = {Synthesis of high quality {low-toxic} semiconductor nanocrystals},
      institution = {University of East Anglia},
      year = {2008},
      type = {{Ph.D. Thesis}},
      owner = {Paul},
      timestamp = {2011.08.25}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage{lmodern}                    

\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chem-angew, articletitle, chaptertitle, language=auto, doi, defernumbers=true]{biblatex} 
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{thesis}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{type}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{institution+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\addbibresource{si.bib}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}    

\begin{document}

\nocite{xu_synthesis_2008}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]