# Biblatex: formatting @article-entry

Tags: biblatex, formatting

I'm currently writing a thesis and have 2 questions concerning biblatex:

- I would like to skip the "Issue" that is up to now always displayed together with "Year"
- I would like to have "Year" at the end

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,ilines]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Bibliographie.bib}
@article{PRL.62.59,
title = {Atomic-Resolution Imaging of Close-Packed Metal Surfaces by Scanning Tunneling Microscopy},
author = {Wintterlin, J. and Wiechers, J. and Brune, H. and Gritsch, T. and H\"ofer, H. and Behm, R. J.},
journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
volume = {62},
issue = {1},
pages = {59--62},
year = {1989},
doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.62.59},
url = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.62.59},
publisher = {American Physical Society}
}
\end{filecontents} 

\addbibresource{Bibliographie.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a test \cite{PRL.62.59}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Right now it's like this:

> J. Wintterlin u. a. “Atomic-Resolution Imaging of Close-Packed Metal Surfaces by
>   Scanning Tunneling Microscopy”. In: Phys. Rev. Lett. 62 (1 1989), S. 59–62. doi:
>   10 . 1103 / PhysRevLett . 62 . 59. url: http : / / link . aps . org / doi / 10 . 1103 /
>   PhysRevLett.62.59.

And it should be like this:

> J. Wintterlin u. a. “Atomic-Resolution Imaging of Close-Packed Metal Surfaces by
>   Scanning Tunneling Microscopy”. In: Phys. Rev. Lett. 62, S. 59–62. doi:
>   10 . 1103 / PhysRevLett . 62 . 59. url: http : / / link . aps . org / doi / 10 . 1103 /
>   PhysRevLett.62.59 (1989).

Would be great if someone could help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: One quick note: I'm pretty sure that you should be using the `number` field rather than the `issue` field (which is meant more for things like 'Summer' 'Spring').  If a journal is published four times a year, you usually have some combination of `volume` and `issue`, where volume refers to the volume for that year, and issue refers to whether it is the first, second, third, or fourth issue of that particular volume/year.

Comment: Hm, thanks for your comment. I want to skip both since the literature I'm using (Science, Nature, PRL, PRB) can mostly be found only by "volume" and "page"...

Comment: Sure, I meant it more as advice on using your entry fields in the way they were meant, not as a solution to your formal output goals. The only time the 'issue' number *needs* to be included is when the journal restarts each issue at p. 1; usually, the page numbering is continuous throughout the year/vol., but if it isn't, then the issue number really needs to be included. By that token, however, IFF you don't want to see the issue number printed, it is actually safer to not include the issue number for journals where it is not wanted. Otherwise, how do you get it back in when you do need it?

Comment: Ok, now I understand... ;)
So I will delete all issue-numbers in the .bib-entrys where they are not needed. But in the case I need them it would be nice to have them appear like: 'author': 'title'. 'journal' 'volume'.'issue', 'page'. 'DOI' ('year').

Comment: Hmm, of course, I should've said, change them to `number` (read `number` everywhere I wrote `issue` in the previous comment; sorry!), and that it is safer to not include a `number` entry where they are not necessary.  Using `issue` is just wrong in this case at the `.bib` file level.  And, of course, there is no harm in leaving in the `number` if you don't mind output like `volume.number` in the ouput (this should be the default).  The extra information does no harm when it appears in the right place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear how you are including all these various types of theses in your `.bib` file, so I'm skipping that (for now at least).  But changing the date location is easily done for article types.  Hopefully it gives you enough information for changing other entry types as needed.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{PRL.62.59,
title = {Atomic-Resolution Imaging of Close-Packed Metal Surfaces by Scanning Tunneling Microscopy},
author = {Wintterlin, J. and Wiechers, J. and Brune, H. and Gritsch, T. and H\"ofer, H. and Behm, R. J.},
journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
volume = {62},
number = {1}, % <-- N.B.: *not* issue
pages = {59--62},
year = {1989},
doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.62.59},
url = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.62.59},
publisher = {American Physical Society}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  % \setunit{\addspace}%
  % \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%               <-- added
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%          <-- added
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}

This is a test \cite{PRL.62.59}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output (minus italics and small caps, etc.):

> J. Wintterlin u. a. “Atomic-Resolution Imaging of Close-Packed Metal
>   Surfaces by Scanning Tunneling Microscopy”. In: Phys. Rev. Lett. 62.1,
>   S. 59–62. doi: 10.1103/PhysRevLett.62.59. url:
>   http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.62.59 (1989).

Comment: I deleted the thesis-question since it was already answered here [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26971/display-a-ph-d-thesis-title-when-using-biblatex-chem)...

Comment: @Baddon -- Ah, good.  I was going to add a bit about that, but hadn't had time to get to it yet....